# String.split() for reading input file

Tags: java, regex, string, input, split

So I have a file I'm trying to parse the line from. It is in the format of

```
Name,_178cm,_AnotherName,_180cm,....
```

*underscores denote whitespace and aren't in the file.*

Right now, I have... (str is the line I'm parsing)

```
String[] arr = str.split(" *,*");
```

but it's giving me a `NumberFormatException`.
What is the problem with my regex??

**EDIT:**

```
String[] arr = str.split(" *,*");
Person per;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    per = new Person(arr[i], Integer.valueOf(arr[i + 1]));
    party.add(per);
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "l"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at rollercoaster.QueueReader.readQueueFile(QueueReader.java:72)
at rollercoaster.QueueReader.<init>(QueueReader.java:25)
at rollercoaster.ProjectRunner.main(ProjectRunner.java:19)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code and the stacktrace?

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 0):

In your case there's no need for a regexp, you can do that with

```
String[] arr = str.split(", ");
```

Anyway, your instruction cannot cause a `NumberFormatException`, because there's no number involved anywhere. You're probably trying to use some of the resulting strings as a number, but failing because of something that's not a number.

**Edit**

From your example code, there are two problems:

1. as already pointed out by @AlexanderRomanov, you cannot cast `180cm` to a number, but you have to remove that `cm` first;
2. you create a new person with name at position `i` and height at position `i+1`, so for `i = 0` the person will have "Name" as `name` and 178 as `height`, but your for loop increments i by one, so the next iteration will try to create a person with `name` 178 and `height` "Another Name".

Here's the code that should solve your problems

```
String[] arr = str.split(",");
Person per;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    per = new Person(arr[i], Integer.valueOf(arr[i + 1].replace("cm", "")));
    party.add(per);
}
```

Note that the for pace is now 2, so that the second iteration will start from 2 and consider "AnotherName" and 180.

Comment: Each person has a height that needs to be parsed as an integer, I believe when the items aren't being added to the array properly, the for loop below it is looking for a number in the second position and there isn't one.

Comment: But you're right about not needing the regex, those implicit instructions were given to me by my teacher strangely enough which is why I was going that route...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp, but you need to **get rid of non-digit symbols** before trying to `parseInt` your token.
Try this:

```
String[] arr = str.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    String name = arr[i];
    int height = Integer.valueOf(arr[i + 1].replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    Person person = new Person(name, height);
    party.add(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to determine from the information you have provided here, we can only guess. I would need to see at least a fragment of the input file to make a suggestion on how to proceed.